# Indefinite articles before non-count nouns

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

Sometimes, I am confused with uncountable nouns. As far as rules are concerned, we can't use an indefinite article before a non-count noun. But at times we break the rules when it follows an adjective.

For example,

1. Have a sound sleep. (Is sleep countable?)
2. He has a great sense of humour. (Is sense  countable?)

Please tell me with which non-count nouns I can use an indefinite article?

Comment: Regarding the questions in your parentheses, a decent dictionary will tell you the category of a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Noncount nouns <s>never</s> seldom take an indefinite article (*a* or *an*) before them (refer [this](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/541/03/))

> 1. Have **a** *sound* sleep.

'Sleep' is enclosed with 'sound'.

> 2. He has **a** *great sense* of humour. (Not *"He as a humour"*)

'Humour' is enclosed with 'sense'; *sense* is countable ('great' is an adjective to describe 'sense'). *"A sense of humour"* is also acceptable.

More examples:

> - A bowl of rice
> - A lot of homework
> - A piece of clothing
> - A clump of cotton
> - An ounce of toothpaste

Indefinite articles can be used when enclosing noncount nouns with other articles such as an adjective or descriptors.

Edit:

There are some idiomatic phrases that include noncount nouns with infinitive articles and also countable.

> Three more *sleeps* till Christmas

This refers to the three nights that pass by.

> Have **a** *sleep*

This is also acceptable in practice

Credits to Andrew Leach and Bill J for the counterexamples.

Comment: What you say generally holds true, but there are actually a very few non-count nouns (usually quantificational ones) which can take an indefinite article, for example "A number of problems remain"; "I feel a touch of frost in the air" and the like.

Comment: Noncount nouns **do** take the indefinite article when identifying a particular instance of the noun. "What was that food again?" "No idea, but it was definitely a rice". In fact your "sleep" sentence is an example of this usage, because "Have a sleep" **is** used like that. "*Never*" is a bit strong, especially in bold.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I've heard of those sentences before. In informal speech, the adjectives that describe the noncount nouns are understood and hence sometimes hidden. Just out of doubt: are you stating that those colloquial instances are grammatically correct? I'll change 'never' to 'rarely' if you prove me wrong. I'm very much interested to know; so far I've only seen 'never' use *'a'* or *'an'* before noncount nouns.

Comment: I also gave you two valid and quite common examples with no adjectives.

Comment: @BillJ: Are you stating *touch* and *number* are noncount nouns? From what I know there are *[touches](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/touch)* and *[numbers](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/number)*. Sorry but I need more counterexamples to confirm (and I'm willing to confirm if there are).

Comment: "Three more sleeps till Christmas"

Comment: Yes, they are. Plurality is not a marker of countability. For example "trousers" is plural but it is still non-count. To qualify as a non-count noun, a noun must be incapable of combining with the cardinal numbers "one, two, three" etc. "Number" in its quantificational sense is non-count since you can't say *"two numbers of problems remain". And Andrew's example with "sleep" is fine too, as in "I think I'll have a sleep".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for the clarification; I'm convinced. I changed the never to seldom.

Comment: @BillJ: Thanks for the examples, but I'm still not convinced that *number* and *touch* are noncount nouns at all. Could you kindly give a reference?

Comment: Yes, The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language by Huddleston & Pullum p349. And here's a link that mentions non-count number with the indefinite article "a" [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2foT6e766G0C&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=Non-count+Quantificational+nouns+Huddleston+%26+Pullum&source=bl&ots=QzP4TRaQE8&sig=Opv3Pl0akrwLK_8GbjKp9LRp9yE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNg8jWk_POAhVIQBQKHTF8AjsQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Non-count%20Quantificational%20nouns%20Huddleston%20%26%20Pullum&f=false)

Comment: To be clear, the link I gave you is not to CGEL, but to another resource that may help you regarding the non-count quantificational nouns like "number".